# how can i allow a question mark in this script?

Tags: php

```
elseif (preg_match("/[^a-z\.^A-Z\.^0-9\._]/",$_POST['content'])) { echo "Comments can only fill normal English letters (a-Z) or numbers!"; }
```

I need it to allow only "? or !" since people might ask questions in the comment box, how can i do this?

thanks

Comment: That regex does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Can you try this? `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+\\??$/`, will match alhpanumbers, underscore and an OPTIONAL question mark a the end.

Answer (score 0):

"/[^a-z.^A-Z.^0-9._\?]/" will add question marks to your match, but this overall method is brute force and gross.

Comment: what do you suggest to prevent it?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent and why? I mean if this is just a comment box I'd allow almost everything a person wants to type, and htmlentities it on the page

Comment: trying to prevent almost anything.
i dont want them to have freedom here, just plain text. but it seems like i need to allow ? or !

Answer (score 0):

You can make special characters literal by prepending `\` (backslash), for example `\?` and `\!`. To match a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscores, literal periods, literal exclamation marks, and literal question marks in a single line, you could use the following: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\!\?]+$`.

I'm not quite sure what specific format you're aiming for... Your current regex doesn't seem to match anything sensible.